# TFS Release - deploy multiple releases on schedule in order of create date/time

Tags: deployment, tfs, release

Using TFS 2017. I have a build definition that creates artifacts to be deployed to WEB and SQL servers. Due to some limitations, each build has incremental package for SQL deployment and full deployment to WEB servers. I have new release created every time new version of artifact is created, but we don't want to deploy right away. Our deployment should start at specific time. So, the release definition has environment that is deployed to on schedule (let's say at 3 AM).

Now, sometimes we have multiple builds running during the day creating multiple releases to be deployed at 3 AM. Everything looks great but... at 3 AM all pending releases are deployed out of order (for example 5, 3, 1, 4, 2). This is not good as release 2 will "wipe out" changes that were added to release 3, 4 and 5.

How do we enforce order of releases to be deployed? I already set schedule for 3 AM, deploy only 1 release at a time and still not getting desired results.

I know there is an option to deploy latest release only, but this will complicate our process a lot (one of the reasons our builds produce incremental packages for database, and yes, release 5 may update same procedure or view that was updated by release 2, so order is important).

It is very strange to be unable to do this simple and very logical deployment type. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean even if you have select the option **Deploy all of them one after another**, you still have this issue?

Comment: Yes. They are being deployed "one at a time" but at random order. In my test, I had releases 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 created and pending deployment. They were deployed in this order: 6, 8, 10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 5, 3, 1, 12, 11, 13, 14, 15. Tried on TFS 2017 and TFS 2018 (on prem) - same.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, this strange and potentially harmful problem of randomly deploying different versions to same environment is "by design".

> I am following up with you to provide you with the review answers we
> got from Product Group.
>
> Answer: “This is one of the expected scenarios where if releases are
> scheduled to run by some time (Scheduled trigger) and if multiple CI’s
> triggering CD’s are generated before the next scheduled run then,
> there are no. of releases queued to be picked by the agents. And when
> the scheduled time hits the queued releases are randomly picked by the
> agents and we see the difference in order of execution and creation.”
>
> Recommendation: In YAML pipelines there is an option available to
> allow these releases run in sequence in which they were generated but
> in classic pipelines we only have the option deploy the most recent
> release and cancelling the older ones. Though as the older releases
> are also available but not deployed and if in case any revert to the
> previous version is required, they can be deployed accordingly.

I did not try YAML version yet. And this is not a solution for us in nearest future a we are trying to upgrade to TFS 2017 (before we can convert most of our builds from XAML to vNext).